# Reset the state before render in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-native

I am using react with Meteor and my data is coming from `createContainer`

```
export default createContainer((props) => {
const { search } = props.dataTables.favorites;
let data = [];

data = Meteor.user().favorites;

return { data };
}, StarredListView);
```

Now I wanted to do some processing on the data after state intialization

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        data: props.data
    };

    this.resetOldData = this.resetOldData.bind(this);
}
```

Now how can I make sure that before render the data my `resetOldData` called and reset the state. Where can I call this this function to reset my state.

```
resetOldData() {
    Meteor.call('reset.old.favorite.data', (err, res) => {
        if (err) { this.props.renderAlert(err.reason, null, true); }
        if (res) {
            this.props.renderAlert(res.message);
            this.setState({ data: res });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So... what's the question?

Comment: how can I make sure that before render the data my resetOldData called and reset the state. Where can I call this this function to reset my state.

Comment: @ZaidIqbal You can call from react lifecycle hook--`componentWillMount()`

Comment: @Ricky I tried on componentWillMount() function but it does not work
My state remains the same

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at React lifecycle documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

There are very specific places where you will want to respond to data coming in and how that should effect the state of your component.

Certain changes to the state only belong in very specific places in the lifecycle of a component.

Comment: I tried on react life cycle event but ui control does not shows the data with updated state.